# trimming a datetime field for an entire column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an entire column that I would like to change from a complete datetime field to display only the mm-yyyy.

Comment: And there was nothing on Google about this? Perhaps searching "SQL Server datetime to month year"?

Comment: what is the data type of the column, how the data is stored already and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, Stack Overflow is not a substitute for reading documentation.  Please post what you've tried and how it's inadequate, and perhaps folks can help.

Comment: I have been searching but nothing matches what I need.  I have tried a lot of things out there already but they only return a single value.  I need the entire column to change inside my database.

Answer (score 3):

Don't store it in database. Let your column stay as datetime datatype use the below code to display the date in `mm-yyyy` format

```
Select right(convert(char(10),getdate(),105),7)
```

Comment: I would use `char(10)` instead of `varchar(50)`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - It makes sense... updated